# How can I Debian-package a python application with a systemd unit using stdeb3/py2dsc and dpkg-buildpackage?

Tags: debian-packaging, dpkg-buildpackage, stdeb

What I'd like to do is create a Debian package for a Python3 application and have the package install an associated systemd service, and remove/update it when the package is removed or updated.

I have a Python3 program that I'd like to bundle into a Debian package on Ubuntu 18.04. I've been able to do this successfully with a `setup.py` and the `py2dsc` program that ships with `stdeb3`.

```
$ python setup.py sdist
$ py2dsc dist/mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
$ (cd deb_dist/mypackage-0.0.1/ && dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us)
```

This creates an installable .deb and apart from a weird `py2dsc` dependency on Python 3.6 even though I'm using 3.8, it works well.

`py2dsc` creates a debian staging tree, including `debian/rules` with:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export PYBUILD_NAME=mypackage
%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```

**Next I want to have this package install a systemd service Unit that will run the Python3 program.** I think the service file needs to be called `python3-mypackage.service` to match `<package-name>.service`, because `py2dsc` prepends `python3-` to the package name.

I did some research and found that, rather than hacking the `pre`/`postinst` scripts, the `dh` command in `debian/rules` should have the `--with systemd` option added, and I need to have `dh-systemd` installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. To achieve this, I pause after running `py2dsc`, add the relevant entry to `debian/rules`, and then run `dpkg-buildpackage`.

For reasons I don't understand, there is no mention of `dh-systemd` in the output of `dpkg-buildpackage`:

```
...
   dh_installdocs -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_installchangelogs -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_python3 -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_perl -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_link -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_strip_nondeterminism -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_compress -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_fixperms -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_missing -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_installdeb -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_gencontrol -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_md5sums -O--buildsystem=pybuild
   dh_builddeb -O--buildsystem=pybuild
...
```

I've searched around and although I can find examples of people building python packages, and people building packages with systemd Units, I haven't been able to find an example of someone packaging both a python project and an associated systemd Unit, so I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm wondering if the use of `pybuild` conflicts with the use of `--with systemd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use dpkg-buildpackage, you should create the debian/ directory and all files there according to the [python packaging documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/index.html). This will create a fully compliant to policy Debian package. The stdeb package only offers a quick and dirty method to create a Debian package. If you are meaning to publish this package in a Debian repository, using stdeb is counterproductive.

Using this method, [you can use the dh_systemd helper](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/pkg-systemd/Packaging#Using_debhelper_with_dh_systemd), and activate it automatically using debcompat >= 10. The service file must be packagename.service on the Debian directory.